# Spring Boot: Change the order of the PropertySource

Tags: java, spring

Spring Boot uses a PropertySource order that is designed to allow sensible overriding of values, properties are considered in the following order:

1. Command line arguments.
2. Properties from SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON (inline JSON embedded in an environment variable or system property)
3. JNDI attributes from java:comp/env.
4. Java System properties (System.getProperties()).
5. OS environment variables.
6. A RandomValuePropertySource that only has properties in random.*.
7. Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants)
8. Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants)
9. Application properties outside of your packaged jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
10. Application properties packaged inside your jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
11. @PropertySource annotations on your @Configuration classes.
12. Default properties (specified using SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties).

*But I don't like this. How can I change it?*

Comment: What would you like to change?

Comment: I want to change the priority order.

Comment: Haven't found a solution either but you can work around a bit by design, especially when you require a certain order in which property sources are processed. So for application settings, always use a custom @PropertySource because it will check external first, then internal (so you can start up with fixed defaults and optionally override from an external file). Don't mix settings with application.properties because 9/10 will match before 11.

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to achieve this. open source!!!!

App.java (main method)

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(AppConfig.class);
        SpringApplication app = builder.web(true).listeners(new AppListener()).build(args);
        app.run();
    }
}
```

AppListener.java

```
public class AppListener implements GenericApplicationListener {

    public static final String APPLICATION_CONFIGURATION_PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME = "applicationConfigurationProperties";

    @Override
    public boolean supportsEventType(ResolvableType eventType) {
        return ApplicationPreparedEvent.class.getTypeName().equals(eventType.getType().getTypeName());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsSourceType(Class<?> sourceType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof ApplicationPreparedEvent) {
            ApplicationPreparedEvent _event =  (ApplicationPreparedEvent) event;
            ConfigurableEnvironment env = _event.getApplicationContext().getEnvironment();

            // change priority order application.properties in PropertySources
            PropertySource ps = env.getPropertySources().remove(APPLICATION_CONFIGURATION_PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME);
            env.getPropertySources().addFirst(ps);
            // logging.config is my testing property. VM parameter -Dlogging.config=xxx will be override by application.properties
            System.out.println(env.getProperty("logging.config"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```